# How to print original and duplicate rows one by one using python

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a dataframe with duplicate rows like this**,
0   Joe     December 2017
1   James   January 2018
2   Bob     April 2018
3   Jack    March 2018
4   Joe     December 2017
5   Jack    March 2018

**After using df[df.duplicated(keep=False)], I get output something like this,**
0   Joe     December 2017
3   Jack    March 2018
4   Joe     December 2017
5   Jack    March 2018

**I need to get the output something like this,**
0   Joe     December 2017
3   Joe     December 2017
4   Jack    March 2018
5   Jack    March 2018

Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Give df and column, 0 is in the index,

```
|   0 | 1     | 2        |    3 |
|----:|:------|:---------|-----:|
|   0 | Joe   | December | 2017 |
|   1 | James | January  | 2018 |
|   2 | Bob   | April    | 2018 |
|   3 | Joe   | December | 2017 |
|   4 | Jack  | March    | 2018 |
|   5 | Jack  | March    | 2018 |
```

Use `duplicated` with parameter `keep=False` and boolean indexing:

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
|   0 | 1    | 2        |    3 |
|----:|:-----|:---------|-----:|
|   0 | Joe  | December | 2017 |
|   3 | Joe  | December | 2017 |
|   4 | Jack | March    | 2018 |
|   5 | Jack | March    | 2018 |
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I have edited my question, I am stuck with that kind of issue, can you look into that and help me out

Comment: Do you want to sort on year?

Comment: Sort the dataframe ahead of the indexing. `df.sort_values(3)[df.duplicated(keep=False)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to display both the original and the duplicate rows right below each other:

1- Identify the rows with duplicated values

```
duplicates = df[df.duplicated(keep=False) | df.duplicated(keep='first')]
```

2- Group the original and duplicated rows together

```
duplicates.sort_values(by=list(duplicates.columns))
```

What you will get is a data frame with all duplicates displayed below each other.